# Install Mods for Unreal Tournament 2004

Tags: pc, mods, unreal-tournament-2004

My college will not let me get to other forums where this information is available, but ...

How do you install *.ut4mod files for Unreal Tournament 2004 when double-clicking no longer works? After checking out the UT2004 from [Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com/en/frontpage/), the program runs files on Windows 7 Professional (except for a strange sound volume bug that drives Window's settings for the program to under 10%). However, after downloading lots of mods from [CNet](http://download.cnet.com/), none of the mods can be run. Anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:** Trying to "open" or "run" the files by double-clicking them in Windows prompts the OS to ask me what program to open the *.ut4mod files with. As for going to the wiki: I would love to, but it is blocked.

Comment: What do you mean by "when double-clicking no longer works?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [UT2kx Reg Checker](http://www.jojosan.de/old/include.php?path=content/download.php&contentid=14&download=go) tool and you can happily double-click to install your mods.

If somehow this doesn't help, then as a last resort you can re-install [Patch 3369](http://www.unrealcentral.com/ut2004-unreal-tournament-2004-patch-v3369/). This will reconfigure the bindings so that your *.ut4mod files should work again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are the .ut4mod files associated with UT2k4 so that Windows knows to use that program to open them? Or do you want to run the mods without needing to install original client?

If they're already associated, have you tried rightclicking on the files and choosing "Run As Administrator"? With several .exe's I've downloaded from various sources for various programs, sometimes things just don't want to play nicely in Win 7. The first thing I try if things aren't installing nicely (I'm on Win 7 Ultimate) is Run As Administrator.

Finally, if that doesn't work, I would check out [this page](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:UMOD/Problems), as it has a bunch of UMOD troubleshooting tips. Good luck!

Comment: Would you care to copy and paster the tips into your answer? The link is blocked.

Comment: We can't carelessly copy paste information here due to licensing issues. The UnrealWiki license (mainly it's Non-Commercial clause) isn't compatible with this site's.

Comment: Ah, I was in the process of formatting, so I didn't see this comment added. This site counts as Commercial?

Comment: Yes, it will be by the time we get ads. Besides people are already allowed to scrape this site and put their _own_ ads on top of the content. Also, I think you will find the [formatting FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) interesting, it explains how to do lists and code blocks :)

Comment: Thanks for the link! But seeing as I can't post it anyway due to the licensing conflicts, shall I just forgo further formatting and re-edit my comment to remove it?

Comment: I did a rollback to the previous version, you can edit it to include additional information, but the whole page including the discussion is way too much.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the mods into the Unreal Tournament base folder, the one that stats system on it because I remember having the same problem with installing a mod for Star Wars: Jedi Academy. What I did to fix it was to extract and move the files into `C:\game folder\jediacademy\data\base` and then when you load the game it will load the base files.